# PHP split while loop into 3 columns to avoid page break

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, loops, while-loop

I am using a PHP while loop to get review data from the database. However, when reviews are longer than 1 line is breaks the grid system (I am using Bootstrap 3) and then the page looks messy. I have thought about two solutions, a read more button and show a fixed height for all of the boxes. Alternatively, split the data received from the database into 3 columns so it will not break the page.

Preferably I would like to split the data from the loop so it shows the data in 3 columns. 
[image: Image of the problem]

This is the while loop that fetches the data:

```
        <?php 
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM transactions WHERE order_id = '{$row['order_id']}'"));
        $name = $data['first_name']. ' '. mb_substr($data['last_name'], 0, 1);
        if($row['rating'] == 5) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
        if($row['rating'] == 4) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
        if($row['rating'] == 3) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
        if($row['rating'] == 2) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
        if($row['rating'] == 1) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
      ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="box_review">
          <h3><?php echo $star; ?></h3>
          <h5 class="thin"><?php echo $row['date'] ?></h5>
          <blockquote>
            <p><?php echo $row['comment'] ?></p>
            <footer><?php echo $name ?></footer>
          </blockquote>
        </div> 
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Save yourself a headache and simply use Masonry (JS) to line it up nicely http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Please note that you should not use mysql_ functions anymore as they are unsafe and deprecated since php 5.5

Comment: Where have I used a `mysql_` function? I have only used `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: Isn't this a CSS question, not a PHP one? PHP-wise, you really should be escaping HTML output with `htmlspecialchars()` and also using a prepared statement for DB query in a loop. (Prepare outside, execute inside.)

Comment: @lokers thanks a lot you made my day